# VHDL arithmatic operation between unsigend fixed point number (ufixed) and unsigned number

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I would like to perform some arithmetic operation between an unsigned number and an unsigned fixed point number in VHDL:

```vhdl
signal A : ufixed(11 downto -8);
signal B : unsigned(11 downto 0);
signal C : ufixed(A'range);
```

What would be the best way to perform an arithmetic operation on the integer parts, something like this:

```vhdl
C <= A - B;
```

I could not find any information on converting an `unsigned` to an `ufixed` while keeping the same "value". Do I have to convert `B` to a `std_logic_vector`, pad 0s, and use the `to_ufixed()` procedure?

Is there any sane way to do this type of operations? Thanks for any suggestions!

**Update: add minimal example**

I tried both suggestions using GHDL but still got a error saying: bound check failure at (the assignment operation) line.

Unfortunately I am still having trouble to make modelsim work on my Linux system.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;

entity sub is
  port (
    A : in ufixed (11 downto -8);
    B : in unsigned (11 downto 0);
    C : out ufixed (11 downto -8));
end entity;

architecture RTL of sub is
begin
  -- C <= A - to_ufixed(B, 11, -8);
  C <= A - ufixed(B);
end architecture;
```

Testbench file:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;

entity sub_tb is
end entity sub_tb;

architecture sim of sub_tb is
  -- component ports
  signal A : ufixed (11 downto -8)  := (others => '0');
  signal B : unsigned (11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal C : ufixed (11 downto -8);

begin  -- architecture sim

  -- component instantiation
  DUT: entity work.sub
    port map (
      A => A,
      B => B,
      C => C);

  -- waveform generation
  WaveGen_Proc: process
  begin
    A <= "00000000111110000000";
    B <= "000000000000";
    wait for 100 ns;
    B <= "000000000001";
    wait for 100 ns;
    B <= "000000001110";

  end process WaveGen_Proc;

end architecture sim;
```

```
ghdl -r --std=08 sub_tb
./sub_tb:error: bound check failure at sub_tb.vhdl:16
./sub_tb:error: simulation failed
```

Comment: `Do I have to convert B to a std_logic_vector, pad 0s, and use the to_ufixed() procedure? ` is a yes/no question (No). `Is there any sane way to do this type of operations` is not a specific programming question. Provide a [mcve] with a specific error, show what you've tried.

Comment: @user1155120 I have added a minimal example as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `to_ufixed` function in the `fixed_pkg` package:

```
  function to_ufixed (
    arg                     : UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED;             -- unsigned
    constant left_index     : INTEGER;  -- left index (high index)
    constant right_index    : INTEGER                   := 0;  -- right index
    constant overflow_style : fixed_overflow_style_type := fixed_overflow_style;
    constant round_style    : fixed_round_style_type    := fixed_round_style)
    return UNRESOLVED_ufixed;
```

So, how about:

```
C <= A - to_ufixed(B, 11, -8);
```

Comment: because it's a similar type, you should simply be able to cast it, and the indexing will be aligned. `C <= A - ufixed(B);` . The "-" function will automatically set all operands to the longest. to_ufixed would be the "proper" way.

Comment: But `B` only has 12 bits, the same length as the integer part of `A` and `C`. `to_ufixed` would expect the signal to be converted to have the same length as the resultant so it can interoperate the binary point bit, wouldn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these suggestions seem to work, at least with Vivado xsim simulation. They are causing very strange errors, e.g. saying that A is not declared (no typo after careful checking, I do realize that I missed : in my original post). The error log is not very informative and I guess I need to investigate a bit more time.

Comment: XSim has terrible VHDL 2008 support. Try a simulator thats not broken. It doesnt matter that B is only 12 bits - the "-" function converts all operands to the length of the longest. In this case it would append 8 bits for the 2^-n bits

Comment: Both Mathew's and Tricky's methods result in a bounds check during execution.  Subtraction for ufixed is integer part length extending - ` signal C:   ufixed(A'LEFT + 1 downto A'RIGHT);`.  The issue here is an XY problem without a [mcve] demonstrating an attempt nor a specific error. It's not a programming question, it's a speculation, yet both the question and answer have been up voted. (With the correct range for C both 'answer' methods work).  [See fixed_generic-body.vhdl lines 467 - 491](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LghBV.jpg). No wavy hands about Vivado simulator being broken.

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks for pointing me to the source code for the function "-". I got a bound check failure with GHDL 0.37 using both 'answer' methods though.

Comment: Declare C with one more integer bit - `signal C: ufixed(A'LEFT + 1 downto A'RIGHT);`. The source explains why. The "-" implementing function takes the maximum of the left bound of the two operands and adds 1 to define the left index of the result and takes the minimum bound of the two operands to define the right index.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew Taylor's answer is correct, however you will also have to declare `C` differently.

When adding two fixed point numbers of the same size, the result will be 1 bit larger in the integer portion.

Therefore, the `C` should be declared as:

```
signal C : ufixed(12 downto -8);
```

If you happen to do know that the magnitude of your values will stay below 12 bits, or if you would like it to saturate, you can use the fixed point `resize` function, which is described in the user guide.

To learn more about how the fixed point package works, you will want to read the fixed package user guide. It can be found [here](https://github.com/FPHDL/fphdl/blob/master/Fixed_ug.pdf). There is a table in there that shows how to calculate the size of fixed point arithmetic results, based on the operand sizes (it's on the second page).